# Laravel: one to many relationship issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables `students` and `exams`. I want to get the students who have exams as last exam date was before one year from today.
How I can do this query with Laravel eloquent?

Comment: Students who have not had an exam within the last year? Can you show the relation methods from your two models? Are you trying to do this with the query builder?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I want Students who don't have an exam within the last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$students = $students->whereDoesntHave( 'exams', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where( 'created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->startOfYear() );
        } )
```

This should query students who don't have exams created after the first day of the current year. I don't know if this is this date query that you want, but you get the idea.

Assuming:

- relation is correctly defined and named